# Entity framework LINQ query for DB2

Tags: linq, entity-framework, db2

I have been using EF for years with SQL Server but have to use IBM's DB2 for a project.

The LINQ generated query needs to have double quotes around the names but does not.

With EF 5.0 I get, for example:

```
SELECT 
Extent1.TripId AS TripId
FROM dbo.Trips AS Extent1
WHERE '12345678' = Extent1.TripId
```

DB2 requires:

```
SELECT 
Extent1."TripId" AS "TripId"
FROM "dbo"."Trips" AS Extent1
WHERE '12345678' = Extent1."TripId"
```

I see web posts saying the EF adds the double quotes by default. Is there a configuration setting that is required?

Answer (score 0):

Just a comment:

Some of your double quotes might not be required?

```
SELECT 
Extent1."TripId" AS TripId
FROM "dbo"."Trips" AS Extent1
WHERE '12345678' = Extent1.TripId
```